# Will the shell optimize a series of calls chained through pipes?

Tags: shell, optimization

Assuming we have many files (maybe a billion) in the current directory, it would be horrific to use `la` to display all the files. At this point it may be helpful to only show a few files. A natural idea is to use `la | head -n 100`.

My question is, does the Linux shell try to optimize this kind of calls chained by pipes? If it runs plainly, it seems we have to let `la` scan the entire directory then let `head` cut off very few lines at the head. However, it only needs a little obvious optimization, that is, returning directly after reading the information of 100 files, can greatly improve the execution efficiency. So will the shell do this for us?

In my attempts, `la | head -n` performed very well. However `la` also seems to return the result in a very short time, and start a long print. I'm not sure if the optimization exists.

Comment: It depends.  Assuming `la` is a wrapper/alias for `ls`, it depends on if `ls` is implemented sanely.  If it reads all of the directory entries and tries to sort them, then it will not print any data until it has done so and there will be no "optimization".  On the other hand, if `ls` writes some output each time it reads a directory entry, then it will receive a SIGPIPE after the first hundred lines of output and terminate without reading the all of the entries.

Comment: @yacc Yes, thank you for your answer. It corrects a wrong concept of mine that i thought a call like `a | b | c` is done in the order of `a`, `b`, `c` one by one, sequentially. But in fact they run cocurrently, and pipe is acutually a producer-consumer model. The shell will not use any magic, whether optimization exists depending on how the commands are implemented. In our case, `la` will keep yielding strings into `stdin` and `head` will keep consuming lines from `stdin`. Once `head` finishes its job and quits, `la` will know by `SIGPIPE` and stop yielding string. Optimization done, horay!

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes, that's indeed the case. Thanks for your comment. I found another two examples in another [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243350/why-does-using-yes-on-bash-pipelines-%20not-cause-infinite-loops): `yes | true` will end immediately, while `yes | tee >(true) >/dev/null` will never stop, because `tee` will work as a consumer until all producers exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `head` terminates, due to all lines being print, it will cause the shell to terminate the process attached to it. This happens because it will receive a `SIGPIPE` signal' and the default handler for this signal is to do a graceful exit. So `la` would be terminated as soon as the top 100 files have been listed.

You can test it with this simple command pipe:

```
while true; do echo hi; done |head -1
```

Without the `head` command, the loop would go on and on. But here it gets terminated after one line.

' see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243350/why-does-using-yes-on-bash-pipelines-not-cause-infinite-loops

Comment: The shell has nothing to do with it. When the process writing data to the socket writes to a broken pipe, the OPERATING SYSTEM sends the process SIGPIPE. Also, it's not a graceful exit, it's a hard exit... unless in the rare case a program catches SIGPIPE and does something graceful.

Comment: @xpusostomos The default behavior for receiving `SIGTERM` is to terminate the process gracefully. The signal handler for `SIGPIPE` is mapped to `SIGTERM` by default. Yes, it's the operating system that handles this, not the shell.

Comment: I never heard that "SIGPIPE is mapped to SIGTERM" before. I think you're confusing that the default action of SIGPIPE is to terminate the program, which is not the same as saying that the default action of SIGPIPE is the SIGTERM handler. To test this out I wrote a little "yes" program, that prints yes in a loop and captures SIGTERM and piping that to head. SIGTERM handler is NOT called. But if I change the program to capture SIGPIPE then then the handler IS called. So no, SIGPIPE has nothing to do with SIGTERM.

Comment: @xpusostomos The default action for `SIGPIPE` is to terminate the process (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). If you change the signal handler for one signal, don't expect that it will be 'mapped' to other signals.

Comment: Right, so SIGPIPE is NOT "mapped to SIGTERM".

Comment: @xpusostomos The mapping sits in the process signal handler table. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80044/how-signals-work-internally

Comment: there is no mapping. SIGPIPE and SIGTERM are completely independent. @yacc